# Error fetching my saved image name in the folder in nodejs and vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, multer

I uploaded my image using multer middleware

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        // fs.mkdir('../uploads/', (err) => {
          cb(null, './public/images/')
          // console.log(err)
        
      },

      filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-hemmyhtec-${file.originalname}`)
      }
    })
    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
      if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true)
      } else {
        cb(null, false)
        const error = new Error('Wrong File, only image are allowed')
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
```

My Image got saved into the folder and name into the database as file: ("1632760261507-hemmyhtec-1.png").

[image: Log of my saved information together with the file name]

So when ever I fetch my data alongside with the file name in my database I got this below
[image]

```
It added "\" at the beginning \"" and also at the end of the file name.
```

Which gives me an error while fetching in my vuejs code

[image]

Can anyone tell me the Problem or a better way to do it?

Code for creating the file...

```
  const file = req.file; 

   MentorProfile.create({
    file: file.filename,
    profession: req.body.profession,
    about: req.body.about.....
```

Comment: Show a piece of code that saves file name to the database.

Comment: Also, does the filename in a database have quotes?

Comment: When you save object make sure value has no `quotes`. that's what happening here.

Comment: How do I avoid the qoute?

Comment: I have added the code @kost